# SCSS: Dynamically target child with same prefixed class as parent?

Tags: sass

Using SCSS, is it possible to tell a child element to receive a certain style only when it shares a (prefixed) class with its parent, **without** knowing the specific name of the class, just knowing the prefix?

I'd like to avoid having to write specific rules that tell every child with a specific class how it should behave when the parent has the same specific class. Instead, I'd like to create a rule that generally states: »Whenever parent and child share the same class, the child receives this style: …«

(The prefix is intended to help distinguish the class that needs to be matched by the child from other classes, which handle other aspects of the child's appearance.)

A Javascript equivlaent of what I'm talking about:

```
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
const children = parent.querySelectorAll("child");
const prefix = "myClassPrefix_";

// Get prefixed class from parent
let prefixedClass_parent = Array.prototype.filter.call(parent.classList, function (className) {
  if(className.includes(prefix)) {
    return className
  }
});

// Check if child shares class
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  // Apply styles to child with matching class
  if(children[i].classList.contains(prefixedClass_parent)) {
    children[i].style.opacity = 1;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't to this with scss alone, as it prints out css and any logic regarding the dynamic value of `prefix-DYNAMIC` gets lost.

What you can do is to have a scss collection of the possible values of the class names after the prefix and print all of them in this way:

```
$classIds: example example2 example3 example4;

@each $classId in $classIds {
  .prefix-#{$classId} .prefix-#{$classId} {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Which will result in this:

```css
.prefix-example .prefix-example {
  background: yellow;
}

.prefix-example2 .prefix-example2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.prefix-example3 .prefix-example3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.prefix-example4 .prefix-example4 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="prefix-example2">
  <div class="prefix-example1">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix-example2">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix-example3">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix-example4">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

You can also use the prefix as an identifier, in which case any children sharing the prefix with its parent will pick up the style (plain css):

```css
div[class^="prefix2-"] div[class^="prefix2-"]{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="prefix2-example">
  <div class="prefix1-example">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix2-example">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix3-example">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="prefix4-example">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```